# Can't get some plugin samples to work on InDesign

Tags: plugins, adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to develop a new plugin for InDesign. But for now I'm taking a look at some samples that comes with the SDK. 
The fact is that I can't get these plugins to work on InDesign(SnippetRunner for example).
I compile then, get a build successful message and move it to the plugin's InDesign directory, as well as it's resource directory.
They load correctly (cause I get not message error during start up). But the plug-in's tab do not show up. It's like there isn't any plugins in there.

What could be happening ?